# apache rewrite url - Fix Appending the string URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following rule in my apache.

```
RewriteRule ^employees$ /all.php?fitler=employees  [L,QSA]
```

This page has pagination.

So the first page is coming properly, But when I hit page 2(in the pagination button), its adding `&p=2` to the url, then for the 3rd-page im getting both `&p=2&p=3`

[image]

Then the 4th page is `&p=2&p=4`

Not sure how do I fix this.

### Update1:

Requested URL

```
https://example.com/empolyee
```

To be redirected

```
https://example.com/all/php?filter=employee

with pagination(let's say when I check page 3)

https://example.com/all/php?filter=employee&p=3
```

Comment: `But when I hit the page 2`, could you please do mention sample url of that here, so that we are aware which are all parameters in url we need to pick up to send in backend php file.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot

Comment: What is the full URL being requested? That query string doesn't really have anything to do with the `RewriteRule` directive you posted. (That rule will simply append whatever query string was on the original request - but that doesn't seem to be what you are seeing in the screenshot?)

Comment: You are right, but I dont know how to fix it., Updated my question